# What plant is this? (Found in Southwest Germany in June)

Tags: species-identification, botany

The picture was taken in Southwest Germany in June, and they covered the ground of a garden we were at...

[image: Picture of a plant I could not identify]

Comment: Undoubtedly a *Sedum*, but someone with local expertise will have to give the species.  Wikipedia states there are several common species in Europe (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am almost sure this is *Sedum reflexum* (aka *S. rupestre*), in English prickmadam or crooked yellow stonecrop and in German Felsen-Mauerpfeffer. It usually grows at rocky or stony ground, not full of grass.

Distinctive features are the pointed leaves, which are not as round as in *S. album* and also the bended stem (flower stalks are always bend, hence the name *reflexum*). Its' flowers should be yellow.

These features can be seen well at the botanical drawing below (from wikipedia commons).

[image]

The reason I'm not completely sure is that in garden (and on roofs) exotic sedums are often planted.